# Given that $(n^3 - n)(5^{8n+4} + 3^{4n+2})-2017$ gives the same remainder(R) when divided by 3804 for all integers n>=2 then what is the value of R?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I already know that $(n^3 - n)$ is divisible by 6.
I have a hunch that the second parenthesis of 5 and 3 is divisible by $5^4 + 3^2.$
I jus need a hint and clarity on how to proceed further. Plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given that $(n^3-n)(5^{8n+4}+3^{4n+2})-2017\equiv R$ mod $3084$ $\forall n\geq 2$. Now, in particular for $n=3084$, we see that

$(n^3-n)(5^{8n+4}+3^{4n+2})=n(n^2-1)(5^{8n+4}+3^{4n+2})\equiv0$ mod $3084$ and $2017\equiv -1067$ mod $3084$, hence $R\equiv 1067$ mod $3084$.

Comment: Thank a lot......Well how can u all solve these probs so easily?

Comment: Well it's 3804 and not 3084.... Thus the answer is 1787

Comment: But then......U told R is congruent to 1067 modulo 3084...... But the question is R is how much? 
So does this satisfy the solution?

Comment: Well then take $n=3804$ and hence $R\equiv 1787$ mod $3804$. Yes it answers your question as then you can take $R=1787$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can plug in any value $n\geq 2$ you want to find the answer.  What's a value of $n$ that makes the big nasty expression simple mod $3084$?

A bigger hint is hidden below.

> Plug in $n=3084$.